# Executing a python function with a certain timeout on a new thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function called keep_alive

```
class Connection:
    ...
    def keep_alive(self):
        _keep_alive(self.session.keepAliveTimeout)
    ...
```

and I want to execute it every `n` seconds ( with `n` being the value stored in `self.session.keepAliveTimeout`) without interrupting the activities of other activities going on in the main thread. How can I run it in a separate thread where it keeps a timeout and still have the ability to kill this thread from the main thread?

Comment: are you looking to assign 'keepAliveTimeout' a random timeout value ?

Comment: @shekharSamanta `keepAliveTimeout` is a part of the `session` object that gets returned from a rpc call.

Comment: import threading

Add this to your function : threading.Timer(n, keep_alive).start()   .n is number of seconds